# libstdc++ new standard library features support table

Tags: c++, c++11, gcc

Is there a table which specifies the new standards (11 and 14) support for *previous* releases of GNU libstdc++?

I found such table for [compiler](https://gcc.gnu.org/projects/cxx0x.html) and for [current lib state](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/status.html#status.iso.2011).

But how can I determinate if gcc version 4.6 supports `std::queue::emplace` and `std::result_of_t`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The manuals for old versions of the library are all linked from https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs and changes in each version are listed in the release notes e.g. https://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-4.6/changes.html

In the latest version of the [C++17 status docs](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/status.html#status.iso.2017), we now also list the version where the feature was introduced.

Comment: Direct link for my case is https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.6.4/libstdc++/manual/manual/status.html#status.iso.200x . Thanks again.